# Do I need to update CSS to upload new images?

Tags: html, css

I want to start by saying that I did not build said website. I was given FTP access to the site and can download it's entirety.

What we are interested in is replacing the images as they are rather outdated.

If I replace the images (naming them as the ones that exist as of right now), they update just fine.

But adding more does not. Lets say that files are numbered 1-6. If I replace those with the same name, they change. If I add 7.jpg, for example, it does not show in the gallery.

Do I need to update the CSS code or upload it again?

I can provide the code in turn.

Comment: Maybe try clearing browser cache and reload?  Other than that, I'd say to ensure the path to the files, and the reference to their use, is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Without further details it's hard to tell what the problem is, but it looks like either someone hard-coded CSS or hardcoded HTML. But I would really need to see the code.

Please try to copy/paste at least the code for file that should render the images.

Comment: Will post code shortly. I'm on a different pc but I believe I can get a hold of it anyway.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/A3Ch2uAf Here is the code that references the gallery.

Comment: This is only the JavaScript (jQuery) part of the code. I assume from what I see here that the HTML image tags are inside some kind of container (i.e. div) with IDs imagen-clinica and imagen-servicios. This code is used to navigate through this images and create some effects like fade, but there is nothing about the actual creation of the `<img>` tags, so I assume they are either already part of the HTML (hardcoded) or they are dynamically created i.e. by PHP, but if it would be PHP, I would assume that the script would analyse all files inside of a folder and create the respective `<img>`tags.

Comment: I see what you mean. Just from looking at the page source I relate what you're saying; hardcoded image sources.
Something tells me I've not been given full-access to this website.

Answer (score 0):

Your gallery should contain new images' name.

if you upload 7.jpg, this one is not in your gallery I guess.

I think it will not matter if you update the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

A priori, to clear any doubt if the images are in cache, I suggest you refresh the page by typing **ctrl +** R or open a **tab in incognito mod**e.

Comment: Thanks. Definitely not the case. Tried that before and then on a different device (mobile) and it doesn't show the other images.